# How to pass CommonTree parameter to an Antlr rule

Tags: antlr

I am trying to do what I think is a simple parameter passing to a rule in Antlr 3.3:

```
grammar rule_params;


options
{
    output = AST;
}

rule_params
    :   outer;


outer:  outer_id '[' inner[$outer_id.tree] ']';

inner[CommonTree parent]    :   inner_id '['  ']';


outer_id    : '#'! ID;

inner_id    : '$'! ID ;


ID   :  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_' )* ;
```

So the `inner[CommonTree parent]` generates the following:

```
inner4=inner((outer_id2!=null?((Object)outer_id2.tree):null));
```

resulting in this error:

```
The method inner(CommonTree) in the type rule_paramsParser is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
```

As best I can tell, this is the exact same as the example in the Antrl book:

```
classDefinition[CommonTree mod]
```

(Kindle Location 3993) - sorry I don't know the page number but it is in the middle of the book in chapter 9, section labeled "Creating Nodes with Arbitrary Actions".

Thanks for any help.

M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't explicitly specify the tree to be used in your grammar, `.tree` (which is short for `getTree()`) will return a `java.lang.Object` and a `CommonTree` will be used as default `Tree` implementation. To avoid casting, set the type of tree in your `options { ... }` section:

```
options
{
    output=AST;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}
```